# Mini Game - Automatic incrementation value server side

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a game for fun. Now here is my problem:
- I have created a Miner object which harvests stone at a 25/hour rate
- I have a UI which shows how much stone he has.
- Now i need some kind of job who'll check all users and their current stone, the amount of stone they'll get every hour and add it to the their current stone.

This should keep running for as long the server is up. Is there a way to realize this in Laravel?

Kind regards :)

Comment: Store last update on stone and calculate the new amount of stone on each new retrieval of this amount :) . (and store it after each retrieval and change)

Comment: Q: Do the players have to keep their browser open?

Comment: No they don't have to keep their browser open. I kind of did it Alex's way: I kept track of the latest harvest time. Then harvest every time the game field gets refreshed. Calculate the amount of stone and then I update the harvest time.

Comment: Because of this you can just use a timestamp and calculate the value when needed. No needed to run any cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they'll get every hour and add it to the their current stone.

It's huge overhead for your php server-side. You could do this with a cron command on linux or task manager on windows to call script counter, but it is very BAD idea. Imagine you will have 1 million players later, your server will be aborting very often and will work too slow.

You need to calc this harvest at each ping_request or specific_harvest_request for unique user. This will reduce the load. For example:
userA has 10 stone, he leaves game and return to game after 20 hours, when he logins you start your `CalcHarvestMethod` and he gets `20*25=500 stones` added. Harvest has to be calculated by each user, there must not be another initiator for this logic. Call ping_request after every 15 seconds while user online and call `CalcHarvestMethod`in ping_request.

> Now i need some kind of job who'll check all users and their current
>   stone

You should calc just current count of stone of each players, don't count stone that they could earn while they are offline. It's too huge overhead as I said above.

Comment: I have indeed made a Harvest (Looted in my name convention) and kept track of the latest_loot_time. When the game field gets reloaded, the Harvest function gets triggered.

Comment: @ThomasVB But in this case you need to store old value for latest_loot_time for each player?

Comment: yes, then i calculate latest_loot_time with this time, i calculate the amount of stone, add it to the player's stone variable and then reset the latest_loot_time.

Comment: The only issue now is that when the page reloads, it shows the value before the updated data :D But that should be another thread i think when i cannot resolve this :)

Comment: @ThomasVB latest_loot_time - yes that is right logic! But i mean you need to calc it with user owner initiator not server by himself. Client send request to server to CalcHarverst() -> then server looks at latest_loot_time and calc harverst and adds to user who initiated this request. In this request you can send response with updated harves. Client side parses this response and update count harvest in client side(js, as3, c++) don't know what is your server side.